Applying function that takes a list as input and a list as output to a pandas dataframe
I have defined the following function:
def my_function(inputList):
  intermediateList = []
  outputList = []
  S = 0
  for x in inputList:
    S += x
    y = 6*x
    intermediateList.append(y)
  for elt in intermediateList:
    z = S / elt
    outputList.append(z)
  return outputList

In words, my_function outputs the 'sum of the list' divided by (6 * element)
and I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like
data = {
  'Class_ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3],
  'Date': ['1/1/2023','1/1/2023','1/1/2023','1/1/2023','1/1/2023','1/1/2023','1/1/2023','17/4/2022','17/4/2022','17/4/2022','17/4/2022'],
  'Student_ID': [3,4,6,8,9,1,10,5,2,3,4],
  'feature': [1,3,-2,8,4,5,6,0.2,0.1,0.55,0.15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

And I would like to apply my_function to the feature column grouped by Class_ID and here is my code:
df['New_feature'] = df.groupby('Class_ID')['feature'].apply(my_function)
and the desired output looks like
    Class_ID    Date        Student_ID  feature New_feature
0   1           1/1/2023    3           1.00    4.166667
1   1           1/1/2023    4           3.00    1.388889
2   1           1/1/2023    6           -2.00   -2.083333
3   1           1/1/2023    8           8.00    0.520833
4   1           1/1/2023    9           4.00    1.041667
5   1           1/1/2023    1           5.00    0.833333
6   1           1/1/2023    10          6.00    0.694444
7   3           17/4/2022   5           0.20    0.833333
8   3           17/4/2022   2           0.10    1.666667
9   3           17/4/2022   3           0.55    0.303030
10  3           17/4/2022   4           0.15    1.111111

However, it gives the following dataframe instead:
    Class_ID    Date    Student_ID  feature New_feature
0   1           1/1/2023    3           1.00    NaN
1   1           1/1/2023    4           3.00    [4.166666666666667, 1.3888888888888888, -2.083...
2   1           1/1/2023    6           -2.00   NaN
3   1           1/1/2023    8           8.00    [0.8333333333333333, 1.6666666666666665, 0.303...
4   1           1/1/2023    9           4.00    NaN
5   1           1/1/2023    1           5.00    NaN
6   1           1/1/2023    10          6.00    NaN
7   3           17/4/2022   5           0.20    NaN
8   3           17/4/2022   2           0.10    NaN
9   3           17/4/2022   3           0.55    NaN
10  3           17/4/2022   4           0.15    NaN

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.

You should use groupby.transform:
df['New_feature'] = df.groupby('Class_ID')['feature'].transform(my_function)

Also note that you could vectorize your function:
def my_function(s):
    return s.sum()/s.mul(6)

df['New_feature'] = df.groupby('Class_ID')['feature'].transform(my_function)

Or:
df['New_feature'] = (df.groupby('Class_ID')['feature'].transform('sum')
                       .div(df['feature']*6)
                     )

Output:
    Class_ID       Date  Student_ID  feature  New_feature
0          1   1/1/2023           3     1.00     4.166667
1          1   1/1/2023           4     3.00     1.388889
2          1   1/1/2023           6    -2.00    -2.083333
3          1   1/1/2023           8     8.00     0.520833
4          1   1/1/2023           9     4.00     1.041667
5          1   1/1/2023           1     5.00     0.833333
6          1   1/1/2023          10     6.00     0.694444
7          3  17/4/2022           5     0.20     0.833333
8          3  17/4/2022           2     0.10     1.666667
9          3  17/4/2022           3     0.55     0.303030
10         3  17/4/2022           4     0.15     1.111111


@Nayrborcherds check my update, you can also greatly simplify your function

that's very helpful, I am new to Pandas and all that so thank you so much for your help.
